# YouTube V3 API - Playlist - Retrieive Range?

Tags: api, youtube, playlist, favorites

In V2 of the YT APi, playlists were fetched by specifying start index and max results.

In V3, there seems only be the previous and next page tokens (and # of results to return).
Is there a way to get playlist items in a certain position.  Example: items 216-256.

Or is the only way to do it is to keep fetching the token until I get to the position I want.  Which would require sending dozens of requests instead of one to get the items I want.

I would use V2, but playlist videos beyond the first 1000 results can't be retrieved in V2, but it is possible to go beyond 1000 in V3.  I'm retrieving the user's list of favorites.